# Correct indexing in solr

Tags: solr

When I index my files (docx, pdf, html), the files are in my index, but I can't search in the content.
So, searching for the query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gm_core/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true
```

returns all indexed files, but the query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gm_core/select?q=text:*&wt=json&indent=true
```

returns an 0 matches.

---

**Indexing code**:

```
java -Dauto -Dc=gm_core -Drecursive -jar post.jar "{Path-to-a-file}"
```

---

Relevant part of my **schema.xml**:

```
<field name="text_general" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="text_de"      type="text_de"      indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="text"         type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<copyfield source="*" dest="text" />

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" />
    <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Can you provide the query URLs as well ?

Comment: Show your indexing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with copy field declaration. You have used wrong (use camelCase) tag, so it is not able to copy the data.

```
<copyField source="*" dest="text"/>
```

Comment: ...I feel bad now. Thanks alot ^^

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are not saving the content of your fields.
Try to set "stored=true"

Comment: setting `<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>` doesn't work

Comment: Can you tell me how do you trying to query them.

Comment: I added the queries to the question.

Comment: can i see your output on q=* ? and what is the exception on text:*  if there is one?